# How to sync/link my master and remote repository in android studio/Git

Tags: android-studio

I have used a push command however the link is still yellow (where the arrow is pointing) and not green. What am I doing wrong?

[image: android studio]

Comment: May you open up the repo directory in the command line and type `git status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are pushing directly to master, you may need to **git push origin master**

Comment: How do I do that? From Git bash?

Comment: Yes, you can open it from Android IDE. File->Settings->Tools->Terminal and then make sure shell path is pointing to C:\ProgramFiles\git\bin\bash

Comment: Thanks I have set the correct shell path but how exactly do I push directly?

Comment: Just open the bash terminal from the IDE and use the command described above.